# How to handle Application_End event from outside global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net, events

We can attach to this event from global.asax file creating method with name Application_End(). But I need to attach to it like this

```
HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.ApplicationEnd+=OnApplicationEnd;
```

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: I don't see an ApplicationEnd event in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.aspx).

Comment: Do you want to handle Application_End event from outside global.asax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have solved the problem in such way.

```
    public class MyHttpApplication:HttpApplication
    {
        public event Action ApplicationEnd;
        protected void Application_End()
        {
            if (ApplicationEnd != null)
               ApplicationEnd();
        } 
    }
```

In global.asax defined

```
<%@ Application Inherits="MyLib.MyHttpApplication" Language="C#" %>
```

Then in code

```
var app = HttpContext.ApplicationInstance as MyHttpApplication;
app.ApplicationEnd += () => { // do something };
```

Answer (score 3):

Application_End is a special "event" that is called by Asp.net that doesn't belog to the HttpApplication class.

From MSDN
*The Application_Start and Application_End methods are special methods that do not represent HttpApplication events. ASP.NET calls them once for the lifetime of the application domain, not for each HttpApplication instance.*

I think you can have the same behaviour attaching and handler to the AppDomain.DomainUnload event

```
//your global.asax class contrauctor
public GlobalApplication()
        {

            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DomainUnload += ApplicationEnd;
        }


        private void ApplicationEnd(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

Comment: Have already tried. You can handle DomainUnload event only from other AppDomain, not from domain that fired it, because it is fired after unloading whole domain data and it would not invoke event handler.

Comment: I have tested it and It works fine. 
Add a breakpoint at the handler
run the web site
add a white space into the web config and save it to force an appdomain unload it will be called

Answer (score 1):

I know the answer is already given but wanted to also include this way:

```
[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(Bootstraper), "Start")]
[assembly: ApplicationShutdownMethod(typeof(Bootstraper), "End")]
public static class Bootstraper
{
    public static void End()
    {
        ...
    }
    public static void Start()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```